# Points in Excel Charts (VBA)

Tags: excel, charts, series, vba

Is there a way in VBA to identify a point in a chart with something else than its number reference?

When placing the pointer above a section of the chart, it displays the serie number and also some narrative. Is this the "Name" of the point?

Ex: Serie 1 Point "**Europe**" Value: 12 (51%)

I am trying to move away from:

`Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart. _
    SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).MarkerStyle = xlDiamond`

and writing:

`Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart. _
    SeriesCollection(1).Points("Europe").MarkerStyle = xlDiamond`

Comment: AFAIK, the chart points `(Value 12)` and data labels `(Europe)` are all `index` (by number) based and can only be referred to in VBA by their index number. That said, if you wanted to apply formatting or other conditions based on the label or value, you could loop each label / value and test against it's value before setting the condition. In some cases, I've found it necessary to loop through the actual range that plots the data and test my conditions on that.

Comment: can you give an example on how to loop in the population of labels?

Comment: do you mean x-axis (legend) labels? or actual data labels?

Comment: These are Horizontal (Category) Axis label in my case

Comment: what type of chart, just so I can be sure?

Comment: it's a pie chart (xlPie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but AFAIK and remember from my experience, this is the only way to test for Category Axis Labels when looping through charts and act upon the series based on the Category Axis Label.

I have commented the code heavily in order to make it as clear as possible:

```
Sub LoopAxisLabels()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As ChartObject
Dim sc As SeriesCollection

Set ws = Worksheets(1)
Set c = ws.ChartObjects(1)
Set sc = c.Chart.SeriesCollection

Dim aForm() As String
aForm() = Split(sc.Item(1).Formula, ",")
'^^^
'|||get formula (chart data source) for the series collection (Item(1) denotes first series collection on chart
'   assumes only 1 collection on chart)
'   places formula into array separate by comma, based on =SERIES(Sheet1!$F$3,Sheet1!$E$4:$E$8,Sheet1!$F$4:$F$8,1) as example

Dim rLabel As Range, cel As Range
Set rLabel = Range(aForm(1)) 'set the label range (Sheet1!$E$4:$E$8 in the example)

Dim i As Long

For Each cel In rLabel 'loop through actual cells of label and test for label values

    i = i + 1 'use counter to refer to specific chart points (since points will be in order of data listed in range

    Select Case cel.Value2

        Case Is = "Europe": sc.Item(1).Points(i).MarkerStyle = xlDiamond 'Points(i) matches the relative range reference

        Case Is = "...":

        'continue with other Cases...

    End Select

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, this seems not to work with a Pie chart but it went well with a column chart (and probably also with a line chart!). Thank you

Comment: still interested to find out if something can be done with a Pie chart

Comment: @ProtoVB why did it not work with a Pie chart? One problem I do see is that you can not set legend marker styles on a Pie chart, since each series will be a `fill` slice of the pie by default. The code structure itself works on a pie, it's just that it will not update the `MarkerStyle` because it's not possible (nor does it make sense).

Comment: My bad, I had changed the  "display" (PlotBy:=xlColumns/xlRows). Select case does work and enable to amend the data using the designation instead of the Index. I was actually not using "MarkerStyle" but "Interior.Color" (which does apply to any Point of any type of chart). This is resolved, thank you

Comment: @ProtoVB - Glad it worked :) You could combine mine with what @Bob Phillips did below by looping through `.XValues` and testing the value xv and totally get rid of loading the formula into an array and looping through the range. There would be no need to add to the collection as he did, just to be clear. A more elegant solution, indeed.

Comment: I may adapt Bob's suggestion and I agree that is seems more straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

The name does not refer to the point, that has a given name such as S1P1.

What you could do is to store the names and indexes of the XValues in a collection, then use that

```
Dim myValues As Collection
Dim xv As Variant
Dim i As Long

    Set myValues = New Collection

    With Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

        For Each xv In .XValues

            i = i + 1
            myValues.Add i, xv
        Next xv

        .Points(myValues.Item("Europe")).MarkerStyle = xlDiamond
    End With
```

Comment: Apparently this does not work with a pie chart but it does go well with a column chart. Thank you

Comment: XValues is already an array. Isn't using a collection just an extra step? Loop through the array until you find "Europe", and that's the index of the point you want.

Comment: Yes, clearly XValues is an array, but I did it the way that I did for two reasons. Firstly, in response to the question, the OP seemed to want to reference the point by the name. Secondly, that collection allows them to do further actions by name reference, without continually looping.